# Sequelize: .createAssociation() or .setAssociation doesn't update the original object with created data

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I've been stuck on this for a while. Take the following code as an example:

```
models.Summoner.findOne({ 
    include: [{ model: models.RankedStats, as: 'SummonerRankedStats', required: true }],
    where: { summonerId: summonerId, server: server }
}).then(function(summoner) {
    models.RankedStats.create({
        totalWins: 0,
        totalLosses: 0 
    }).then(function(rankedStats) {
        summoner.setSummonerRankedStats(rankedStats).then(function() {
            console.log(summoner.SummonerRankedStats)
            //This outputs undefined

            summoner.getSummonerRankedStats().then(function(srs) {
                console.log(srs)
                //This outputs the RankedStats that were just created
            })

            models.Summoner.findOne({ 
                include: [{ model: models.RankedStats, as: 'SummonerRankedStats', required: true }],
                where: { summonerId: summonerId, server: server }
            }).then(function(summoner) {
                console.log(summoner.SummonerRankedStats)
                //This outputs the SummonerRankedStats object
            })
        })
    })
})
```

So, to put it simply... If I have a Summoner (var summoner)  and perform a .setAssociation() or .createAssociation() on it, and then log summoner, the data created isn't there. If I fetch it again from the database (with .getAssociation() or by searching for that Summoner again) I can access it, but I was hoping to avoid that extra DB call.

Is there a way to add this information to the original object when using .create() or .set()? It can be achieved by doing something like:

```
summoner.dataValues.SummonerRankedStats = rankedStats
```

But that seems somewhat hacky :)

Is there a correct way to do it, or does it even make any sense?

Thanks in advance!